# keyboard ctrl,alt,super still works as shift even after Swoogan/aziokbd

Tags: drivers, keyboard, 18.04, keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

i use laptop but i want to use external usb keyboard for more convenient works. i know that lot of people have problem with this ctrl, alt and super key register as shift. and they all seem successful using this  [Swoogan/aziokbd](https://bitbucket.org/Swoogan/aziokbd) tool in bit bucket.

i tried to install it and change the quirks from 0004 to 0007 and Create a new file in /etc/default/grub.d/.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='usbhid.quirks=0x0c45:0x7603:0x4'
```

but my keyboards ctrl, alt, super still works as shift. i'm using laptop in Ubuntu 18.04

**this is my** `lsusb` output :

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0408:a030 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1c4f:0056 SiGma Micro  //<<< this is my usb keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**this is my** `lsmod | grep -e usbhid -e aziokbd` output :

```
usbhid                 49152  0
aziokbd                20480  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
```

**this is my** `/etc/modprobe.d/usbhid.conf`

```
options usbhid quirks=0x0c45:0x7603:0x0007
//i change it to 0004 and 0007 still not works
```

Answer (score 0):

After couple hours of googling I finally found a solution from some of ubuntu forums. Type this in your terminal :

```
sudo modprobe usbmon && sudo tcpdump -i usbmon3
```

wait couple seconds and just press each key on your keyboard that doesn't work. Sometimes my keyboard becomes weird and starts typing 'Enter' key in endless cycle.

Unfortunately it's working until next system reboot.

Hope it will help for you too :)